# Find the angle of a pendulum given the time

Tags: calculus, rotations, classical-mechanics, angle

You are given a pendulum with the distance $d$ from the anchor point to the center of the massive sphere, radius $r$ and mass $m$. Gravity is given by $g$.

[Pendulum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4fQI.png)

I want to derive a formula for the angle $\theta$ between the vertical axis and the rope, given the time $t$ since the pendulum was dropped with the angle $\theta_0$. Let $\omega$ be the angular speed and $\alpha$ be the angular acceleration. At time $t=0$, let $\theta=\theta_0$ and $\omega=\omega_0$.

The torque applied to the pendulum is given by $\tau=d \bullet mg\sin\theta$.

The inertia of the pendulum is given by $I=\frac{2}{5}mr^2+md^2$.

Newton's 2nd law for torque gives: $\sum\tau=I\alpha$ which solved for $\alpha$ gives

$$
\alpha=\frac{dmg\sin\theta}{m(\frac{2}{5}r^2+d^2)}=\frac{dg\sin\theta}{\frac{2}{5}r^2+d^2}
$$

Due to $\alpha$ not being constant, we have to use the integral forms for the rotational kinematics formulas, which are

$$
\theta=\theta_0 + \int_0^t\omega\, dt
$$

$$
\omega=\omega_0 + \int_0^t\alpha\, dt
$$

Using the latter one, we get

$$
\omega=\omega_0 + \int_0^t \frac{dg\sin\theta}{\frac{2}{5}r^2+d^2} \, dt
$$

Then the first one

$$
\theta=\theta_0 + \int_0^t
\omega_0 + \int_0^t \frac{dg\sin\theta}{\frac{2}{5}r^2+d^2} \, dt
\, dt
$$

And this is how far i get with my knowledge. I can't think of any way to solve this integral, because of the dependence of $\sin\theta$. Might this be a (non-linear 2nd order) differential equation?

I hope the steps I've done are correct, please let me know if they are not. I hope someone here is able to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a well-known problem. An even more fun variation is to start at the bottom but give the weight an impulse to make it swing. If you give enough impulse, the weight will travel in a complete circle. I don't think there is a closed-form solution. In introductory physics classes they will typically do the small-angle approximation of this problem, whose solution is simple harmonic motion.

Comment: The motion of a pendulum is modelled by a 2nd order differential equation. A lot of information on pendulums can be found at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics). The differential equation modelling the motion of pendulums can be solved numerically, using e.g. Runge-Kutta methods. I'm not aware of an analytical solution to the pendulum problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time law of the *physical pendulum* is the solution of the following *Cauchy problem*:

$$
\begin{cases}
-m\,g\,d\sin\theta(t) = I\,\ddot{\theta}(t) \\
\theta(0) = \theta_0 \\
\dot{\theta}(0) = \omega_0 \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \overset{\alpha\,:=\,\sqrt{\frac{m\,g\,d}{I}}}{\Rightarrow} \quad \quad
\begin{cases}
\ddot{\theta}(t) + \alpha^2\sin\theta(t) = 0 \\
\theta(0) = \theta_0 \\
\dot{\theta}(0) = \omega_0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

where, in the proposed case, we have $I = \frac{2}{5}\,m\,r^2+m\,d^2$.

Due to its heavy non-linearity it cannot be integrated elementarily, so two ways are presented.

---

We can reduce it to a *system of first order ODEs*:

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{\theta}(t) = \omega(t) \\
\dot{\omega}(t) = -\alpha^2\sin\theta(t) \\
\theta(0) = \theta_0 \\
\omega(0) = \omega_0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

and consequently apply a numerical method such as, for example, *Euler's method*:

$$
\begin{cases}
t_k = t_{k-1} + \Delta t \\
\theta_k = \theta_{k-1} + \omega_{k-1}\Delta t \\
\omega_k = \omega_{k-1} - \alpha^2\sin(\theta_{k-1})\Delta t
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \quad \text{with} \; k = 1,2,\dots,n
$$

where $\Delta t := T/n$ with $T>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are fixed parameters.

---

We can content ourselves with studying the physical pendulum with *small angles* ($\theta \ll 1\,\text{rad}$):

$$
\begin{cases}
\ddot{\theta}(t) + \alpha^2\,\theta(t) = 0 \\
\theta(0) = \theta_0 \\
\dot{\theta}(0) = \omega_0 \\
\end{cases}
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
\theta(t) = \theta_0\cos(\alpha\,t) + \frac{\omega_0}{\alpha}\,\sin(\alpha\,t)
$$

which, being a *linear ODE of the second order*, is elementary integrable.

---

As an example, assuming $\alpha=3$, $T=10$, $\theta_0=5°,10°,\dots,90°$ and $\omega_0=0$:

[image]

where the blue sine wave is exact, while the red one is approximate.